# Bounding box of autocomplete - Jquery UI Map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3

I am using jquery.ui.map.js V3.0-beta to load a map and to create a autcomplete search input above it.

How can I set the bounds of the search? I am creating it as follows

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('autocomplete', input, function(ui) { 

       ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean set the bounds around the area typed in the autocomplete search? For example, if "California" is typed, have the map show the whole state?

Comment: @HeitorChang Set the bounding box of the autocomplete search so that it only searches/autocompletes within the specified bounds